# Unable to set margins in Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a class which extends "ListView".
In the constructor, I would like to set margins using this code :

```
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    params.setMargins(10,0,0,0);
```

For an unknown reason, i don't have a "setMargins" method on params...
It's strange because if in an activity, I create a new ListView, i can use params without any problems.
I think it's very obvious, but i don't know why, i can't find a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong `LayoutParams` class. Try to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: Like I said, it's certainly obvious... It was. So it works. Do you know why I don't have this problem if i create a new listview in an activity ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Also don't forget to call `requestLayout()` when you done.

> Sets the margins, in pixels. A call to requestLayout() needs to be
>   done so that the new margins are taken into account. Left and right
>   margins may be overriden by requestLayout() depending on layout
>   direction.

Comment: @IronRabbit it will crash you if you try placing your costume view in RelativeLayout using Moran solution.

Comment: I've corrected my code. Indeed, if i use LinearLayout.LayoutParams it works, but the margins are totally ignored. It works fine, with the good behavior, if I use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. BUT, it doesn't work at all with ViewGroup, i've the same error ;)